# How to make Windows Forms UserControl auto-resizing to docked content?

Tags: c#, user-controls, devexpress, windows-forms-designer, autosize

I have a `UserControl` which I'm going to place into a DevExpress `PopupControlContainer`.

I want the `UserControl` to auto-size to fit at least its content, which is a `PanelControl` containing two buttons, docked to the bottom, and a `ListBoxControl` docked to fill the rest.

The UserControl's and panel's `AutoSize` property is True and while it is not docked, it also behaves correctly and does not shrink past its content. The `UserControl` also does not shrink past the panel while it is not docked.

But I want the panel to be docked to the bottom while still restricting the UserControls minimum width so that its content stay completely visible.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Affect the `Dock` property at the time of creation of `UserControl`  object like this:

```
UserControl myUserControl= new UserControl () { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
```